# How to prevent override the setting using .htaccess or custom php.ini

Tags: php, security, apache, .htaccess

How to make sure the user cannot override the setting using .htaccess or custom php.ini
any tips for configuration i should use

Comment: What settings? Settings in the PHP.ini file cannot be overwritten in the .htaccess, but can easily be overwritten in any PHP file.

Comment: like if i set register_globals = Off  in my main php.ini some users can create a custom php.ini inside their account and will get this value on , i need to force system to ignore all these custom setting and read only php.ini " the main file "  values which is already off

Comment: @animuson - A lot of settings can indeed be overridden in .htaccess using the `php_value` directive (and others).  See [the PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.php)

Comment: @daiscog I need to prevent this overridden :) any tips to secure my box ?

Comment: @marco: some directives simply cannot work from within a script. register_globals is one of them. By the time the ini_set() is reached in the script, the setup/initialization phase of PHP is long over.

Comment: If you need fine-grained control over what's allowed in PHP files and what not, why not write your own parser script?

Comment: @dambrisco ...or use your master php.ini to disable certain functions

Comment: @daiscog - If PHP parses directory-level INI files, though, would that work? (If PHP doesn't always parse directory-level INI files, my mistake. I was assuming that was true.) --- Just saw your edit on your answer. Disregard this - the obvious solution is to programmatically update the master INI file whenever a new host is added.

Comment: @dambrisco Not all directives can be set in directory-level ini files.  `disable_functions` can only be set in the main php.ini file.  See the [list of directives](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/ini.list.php) for more info on what can be set and where.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To prevent users setting PHP config values in .htaccess files, do not give `AllowOverride Options` permissions on their virtual hosts.

Alternatively, install PHP as CGI instead of as an Apache module, as the CGI version is unaffected by .htaccess files.  However, since PHP 5.3.0, PHP CGI does parse per-directory php.ini files.  I am not aware of a method that turns this off.

EDIT:  I've just seen this in the latest default php.ini:

```
; Directives following the section heading [PATH=/www/mysite] only
; apply to PHP files in the /www/mysite directory.  Directives
; following the section heading [HOST=www.example.com] only apply to
; PHP files served from www.example.com.  Directives set in these
; special sections cannot be overridden by user-defined INI files or
; at runtime. Currently, [PATH=] and [HOST=] sections only work under
; CGI/FastCGI.
; http://php.net/ini.sections
```

So if you put directives in your main php.ini under per-directory headings they cannot be overridden.  However, the downside is that you'll have to do this for every virtual host so it'll be a PITA in environments where there are many or where new ones are frequently added.

EDIT AGAIN:

Further reading has revealed this:

```
; Name for user-defined php.ini (.htaccess) files. Default is ".user.ini"
;user_ini.filename = ".user.ini"
; To disable this feature set this option to empty value
;user_ini.filename =
```

So just uncomment that last line to disable per-user ini files.  :-)