# Is it possible to force error reporting through LAMP?

Tags: php, error-handling, lamp

I'll keep it simple and add details if requested.

I have some of those Clients that simply love to add random files everywhere... ie: having 20 .htaccess files in a website.

I know the correct way would be : clean up the site and post only 1 htaccess file.

But, i don't always have the time for that.

Would it be possible to set a Default "Report ALL errors, ignore other instructions regarding the matter" inside LAMP.

I figured that since it's a local developpement, there's no apparent reason to hide errors.

I've tryed the following .htaccess file (and some other variations) in my root folder, but it's not working so well :

```
php_flag display_startup_errors on
php_flag display_errors on
php_flag html_errors on
php_value display_errors On
php_value error_reporting E_ALL
```

Frameworks disable them.

Other files overwrite them.

Other stuff may or may not happen. - There's always other stuff -_-' .

#

First Edit :: Worked for me.

#

File location : `/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini`

modified lines :

```
display_errors = On
error_reporting = E_ALL
user_ini.filename = ".user.ini"
```

From terminal :

```
service apache2 restart
```

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7841709/how-to-prevent-override-the-setting-using-htaccess-or-custom-php-ini

Comment: `if ( file_exists('.htaccess') && is_writeable('.htaccess') ) unlink('.htaccess');`

Comment: Currently checking out Salketer's answer. seems like php.ini would be the way to go. I'll update what lines I've edited once I get it to work.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3193072/strict-mode-in-php

Comment: Strict mode won't do it. applying it inside a framework scrambled by a client is hell and leaves traces. >> Solved my question using Salketer'S reference. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since there's many similar duplicates, I'll post the simple solution I used.

File location : `/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini`

modified lines :

```
display_errors = On
error_reporting = E_ALL
user_ini.filename = ".user.ini"
```

From terminal :

```
service apache2 restart
```