# Give the php.ini timeout value precedence over a script?

Tags: php, drupal

In my framework I have a script overriding my php.ini settings and setting a lower timeout limit.

Is there a way to give the php.ini value precedence over script?

Comment: in short no, so just edit the script

Comment: In addition to disabling the `ini_set()` function as mentioned by Marc B, see [How to prevent override the setting using .htaccess or custom php.ini](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7841709/how-to-prevent-override-the-setting-using-htaccess-or-custom-php-ini) for details on disabling the other places (.htaccess, custom php.ini) that configuration values can be set.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can outright disable the `ini_set()` function via the [disable_functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.disable-functions) option. But otherwise, no. you cannot force the .ini settings to override the ini_set overrides otherwise.