# Wordpress: undefined notice error showing but php errors disabled?

Tags: php, wordpress

In **php.ini** file i have `display_errors = off` and `display_startup_errors = off`.  Also in the `functions.php` i have `error_reporting(0);`

In **wp-config.php** i have at the top 
`error_reporting(0); @ini_set('display_errors', 0);`  I also have `define('WP_DEBUG', false); define('WP_DEBUG_LOG', false);`

Errors are still showing?

I get numerous `Notice: Undefined variable:`, `Notice: Use of undefined constant` etc.  I'll debug them later but what can i do to hide them?

Comment: can you try putting this code in a script & run using browser: `<?php phpinfo(); ?>`

Comment: it may happen that another `INI` gets loaded for your server instance which can not be overridden by wordpress.

Comment: From looking at php.ini i can see for local value, `display_errors = on` and master value is off.  Does this mean there may be a file in wordpress setting display_errors?

Comment: No. just share `phpinfo` output so that I can help you further.

Answer (score 0):

It may happen that another `INI` gets loaded for your server instance which can not be overridden by wordpress.

> You should look for any local INI in your wordpress installation root & try disabling errors there.

There is one useful answer which may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7841902/2004910